# How to append google street view image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried two different codes but neither worked.

```
$("#search").click(function(){
var citySearch = $("#city").val();
var map = $("map");
var streetView = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="+ citySearch + "";
map.append('<img src="'+ streetView +'">')

})
```

and also used this with the button being onclick myFunction and onsumbit myFunction

```
function myFunction(){
var citySearch = $("#city").val();
var map = $("map");
var streetView = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="+ citySearch + "";
map.append('<img src="'+ streetView +'">')

}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="" id="city">
<button id="search" onsubmit="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<div id="map">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe even some HTML or an idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've updated the question with HTML. What I'm trying to do is users input to be added to the string and the picture of streetview append to the div called map.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example doing what you are trying to do. Notice that I just changed a few things. Instead of replacing the html inside the div, I just added a default image and changed the src. Also, your click function code was not actually calling the myFunction() code. I changed that a bit too to call the main function directly from the click function. Just enter "park" or any other working example into the textbox to see it work in the snippet below.

```js
//Page ready
$(function(){
//On clicking "search" run the function below to replace the image source
    $("#search").click(function() {
        myFunction();
    });
});

//Function to get city entered and replace the image src, therby changing the image
function myFunction() {
    var citySearch = $("#city").val();
    var $mapImage = $("#mapimage");
    var streetView = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=" + citySearch + "";
    $mapImage.attr("src", streetView);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" id="city">
<button id="search">Submit</button>

<div id="map">
   <img id="mapimage" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=maine" />
   <br />
   <i>Enter "park", or "maine" for example</i>
</div>
```